# Unable to connect Azure RM VM from local system

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-load-balancer

I have created one Azure RM VM, and I want to connect to VM from my local desktop/ company network.

How to achieve this?
Also how to use Azure Load Balancer to achieve this functionality?

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to connect Azure VM with private IP? You need a site-to-site VPN.

Comment: If you use Public IP, you could connect your VM easily.

Comment: Any update about this?

Comment: I had followed the steps while creating VM from Azure Portal.It created Public IP address. This newly created VM cannot be connected from my local machine. Any other setting to be done?